# View only showing one row from sql result set

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, joomla-4.x

I am creating a component and trying to display a list within a model.  The code I have shows the multiple arrays that should be on the list, but when I add echo inside the view table, I am only getting one result each time.

```
$db    = Factory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select("*")
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__football_player'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('teamid') . ' = ' . $db->quote($value) . ' AND active = 1');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
    
foreach($results as $result) {
    $playid = $result->id;
    $players = explode(',', $playid);
    print_r($players)
}
$this->_item->players = $players;
$this->_item->lname = $result->lname;
```

The `print_r()` is showing both items, but the table on the frontend only shows one, or if I move my print outside the brackets it goes down to one as well.

For more context:

Here is a sql fiddle with some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d08e77/1.

The page currently loads all the details from `#__football_team` and lists it on the page, but looking to have a list of `#__football_player` below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that this is a very basic task.

I would pass the entire players result set to your view via `$this->_item->players`.

```
$query
    ->select("*")
    ->from($db->qn('#__football_player'))
    ->where(
        [
            $db->qn('teamid') . ' = ' . $db->q($value),
            "active = 1"
        ]
    );
$db->setQuery($query);

$this->_item->players = $db->loadObjectList();
```

This will generate an empty array or an array of object.

In your view, use a foreach to iterate each row and then access column data using property syntax (`->`).

Comment: mickmackusa, thank you so much.  I would love to learn more from you, do you offer tutoring or 1 on 1 services?  I would be willing to pay, you have a lot of knowledge and great input that would be great to learn in my learning of php and joomla mvc.

Comment: I have apparently fooled you. I am not a subject matter expert (SME) in Joomla.  The truth is, I no longer use Joomla in my career.  I merely share what I know and keep quiet when someone asks for something that I don't know -- this gives the illusion of expertism.  Please keep engaged with this community, read as much of the content as you can, ask questions when you have them.  We will help you if/when we can -- together.  This is the Joomla way.